# Bounding the degrees of sparse graphs

Tags: probability, inequality

This is Exercise 2.4.2 of the book High-Dimensional Probability by Vershynin. It is supposed to be simple, but I’m stuck on how to prove it. The exercise is the following:

Consider a random graph $G(n,p)$ with expected degrees $d=O(\log n)$. Show that with high probability (say 0.9), all vertices of $G$ have degree $O(\log n)$.

To see if I understand correctly, what we need to show is that there exists $C \in \mathbb R_+$ such that $P(\forall i, d_i \leq C \log n) \geq 0.9$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're given that $d\le M\ln n$ for all $n$ large. Choosing $C>0$ s.t. $\alpha\equiv eM/C<1$, and using  Theorem 2.3.1,
$$
\mathsf{P}(d_i\ge C\ln n)\le e^{-d}\left(\frac{ed}{C\ln n}\right)^{C\ln n}\le \alpha^{C\ln n},
$$
where $d:=(n-1)p$. Thus,
$$
\mathsf{P}(\forall i:d_i\le C\ln n)\ge 1-n\alpha^{C\ln n},
$$
and the bound on the RHS is small when $C$ is sufficiently large.